# How to do split array of object in javascript?

Tags: javascript

`[{"e":"01-25-01-006"},{"e":"01-02-05-001"}],` I have this.

`[ 01-25-01-006,01-02-05-001 ]`, I need this format of array

Comment: Your desired output's syntax is invalid.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array/46694321#46694321

Answer (score -1):

You can use `map` to get the desired outcome:

```js
let data = [{
  "e": "01-25-01-006"
}, {
  "e": "01-02-05-001"
}];
console.log(data.map(entry => entry.e));
```

Comment: Although correct, you are likely being voted down for answering a poor question that has many duplicate answers

Comment: If the question gets downvoted and close-voted, that is a clear indicator that it should not be answered ...

Comment: That's fine. Semi-new to answering questions on SO. Getting the hang of it, thanks.